# AES Decrypt a column in MS Excel

Tags: vba, excel, encryption, aes

In my excel files I have a column which has AES encrypted strings. I know the "key" used to encrypt these strings. Is there a way to AES decrypt an Excel column using this "key"?

Comment: http://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/906850-aes-encryption-algorithm-vba-vbscript